# How do I manipulate a CSV file?

Tags: javascript, java, inputstream

Create a program in Java that will read the CSV file and compute the Final Grade of the student using the computation below:
Lab Exercise * 30% + Long Quiz * 30% + Alternative Assessment * 40% = Final Grade
Then, display the final grade of each student.

We will be using the java.io package and so far this is what I come up with

```
import java.io.*;
public class ReadingFile {
public static void main (String[]args){

    try{

        File myFile = new File("Grades.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
        String allLines = "";

        while((allLines = br.readLine()) != null){
            String row [] = allLines.split(",");
            double finalGrade = (Double.parseDouble(row[1])*.30) + (Double.parseDouble(row[2])*.30) + (Double.parseDouble(row[3])*.40);

        }

    }
    catch(IOException err){
        System.err.println("File not found.");
        
    }
}
}
```

I know that there are a lot of missing code but this is all what I can do with the best of my knowledge and abilities.

Comment: Not too bad as a new Java programmer, few tips here: 1. never use double, use BigDecimal instead, you will run into precision problems. 2. don't forget about your empty string check and null pointer check. 3. try not to reinvent the wheel and use common libraries to manipulate csv instead e.g. [Apache Common CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)

Comment: Heyo!! this may be a little bit late but I just recently unlocked the comment privilege. I just wanted to say thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

Assume your content of `Grades.csv` is as below

```
35,91,24
53,63,73
13,23,33
```

Some tips

1. Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to ensure that BufferedReader is closed at the end of the statement.
2. Java uses zero-based indexing, so you should use `row[0]` to read the first score.
3. Use a [logger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or `e.printStackTrace()` to help you debugging.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Grades.csv")))) {
        String allLines;
        while ((allLines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = allLines.split(",");
            double finalGrade =
                (Double.parseDouble(row[0]) * .30) + (Double.parseDouble(row[1]) * .30) + (Double.parseDouble(row[2]) * .40);
            System.out.println(finalGrade);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("some error message");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
47.4
64.0
24.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to finally answer the problem thanks to your help. I have another question, now that I have gotten the output. how can I append it to the next row for each column?

Comment: You can not write and read same file simultaneously. Or do you mean write the output to another `output.csv`?

Comment: Heyo! this may be a late reply, but after looking at different materials I've discovered that I cannot really read and write the same file simultaneously. Nonetheless, your answer was a great help.